# update items using jsGrid

Tags: javascript, php, jsgrid

I wanna use the jsGrid library into my site web, can you help me? I will be very thankful.
How can I send the updated items to the php code update.php? 
This is what I have tried but it doesn't work for me. I get white cells:

```
  updateItem: function(item) { 
     var d = $.Deferred();
       $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "update.php",
                data:{name:item.name}
            }).done(function(response) {
                d.resolve(response);
            }).fail(function() {
                d.resolve(previousItem);
            });
            return d.promise();
    }
```

update.php:

```
<?php
include("connexion.php");
$sql = "UPDATE servers SET name = '".$_GET['name']."' WHERE id = 1";
if( $result = pg_query($sql))    
{  
echo 'Data Updated';  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the sample project for php + jsgrid  https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php. 
It shows how to implement update correctly on both the front-end and back-end sides.

Comment: yes the project helped me, but  the select field still not working, i don't know how to update the select fields , It updates just his id in the database

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about select field in the original question. The data updated in the DB depends on your backend script implementation (not js-grid). Also in your code in the original question you update the `name` field, not `id`, so `id` field should not be updated.

Comment: Thanks you tabalin :)